# Accessing iPhone data from a Mac OS X application?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, macos

Is there a class library or an Objective-C framework which could permit me to access my iPhone data from a Mac OS X application?

For example, if I develop an application to edit pictures, I would like access to my iPhone pictures from this application without using iTunes. I connect my iPhone as USB device and pictures are displayed into the application.

Comment: without jb you can use iExplorer or iFunBox http://i-funbox.com/ifunboxmac/

Answer (score 0):

Apple doesn't support this mode for (recent) iDevices.  There are some apps (mainly on Windows) which can sort of do this kind of thing, but I don't think you're going to find any libraries to make it simple.  You may want to check the jailbreaking sites.  They might provide better information.

Comment: iExplorer is one such app which doesn't require jailbreaking http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/

Comment: Thank you, I don't want jailbreak my iPhone.
I'm continuing my research.

Comment: You don't have to jailbreak.  But the jailbreakers use these techniques to get raw access to the device in order to modify them or to examine the filesystem contents.  They might be able to help you find code to perform the function you're after.